# Create an image link on a site (not QuickLaunch) that opens an InfoPath form

Tags: 2010, infopath, hyperlink, image

As the title suggests I have a task where I'm required to create a link on a page with an image. When the user clicks the image link it will then open an InfoPath form for them to do whatever they need.

For example, on a SharePoint site, there is an image of a dog (doesn't really matter) and when a user clicks on the image it opens up an InfoPath form.

I have been searching and the only things I have ran across are how to open an InfoPath form via a link in the Quick Launch and so forth. May I get some help on a How To article or suggestions? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert the picture you want to use, and while the picture is still selected, select insert from the ribbon again and choose insert Link. Leave the `Text to display` blank and paste the Url. Save the page.

Now when anyone click on the image, the link should open.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the InfoPath form you want to link to (I'm assuming this is attached to a SharePoint list or library) and open it by clicking on New item or New document on the list or library. With it open copy the URL from your web browser - that is the link you will use to add to the picture.

I'm not sure if you need to know how to add a picture to your sight but if you do, here is a good YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65VUeV8C2N8, you'll use the URL link in the first step.